# what is the meaning of unbalanced #endif

Tags: c

While running a loadrunner test my friend got a `unbalanced #endif in global.h` error. I did some googling but could not find exactly what could have caused this error.

Its not that there are not web pages with this text but they do not clearly state what this error means and what could be causing this error.

Could the experts here tell me what this error means and what could be causing it?

Comment: It's pretty clear - there's an `#endif` somewhere without a matching `#if` directive.

Comment: It might be `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If means that there is an extra `#endif` in your header file somewhere.

Something like:

```
#if (something) // or #ifdef or #ifndef
// some code
#endif
#endif // extra, unbalanced
```

Make sure you don't have a misspelled `#ifndef` somewhere in a .h file, which is a common mistake.